# TextView textSize behaving differently now

Tags: android

The documentation for `setTextSize()` on TextView says, effectively, that it is expecting units of "SP".  I have `TextViews` that set their `textSize` attribute through databinding.  When I updated Android Studio today to 3.1, the behavior seems to have changed and `setTextSize()` now seems to expect pixels.  Is anyone else seeing?

Comment: I don't see how the IDE (Android Studio) would have any affect on the SDK. But you can always use the override `setTextSize` method that takes the unit type `setTextSize (int unit, float size)` which would be `COMPLEX_UNIT_SP` in the case of "SP"

Comment: That was quite puzzling to me as well.  I saw that override, but I am binding to the xml attribute.  In any case, it was fairly straightforward for me to work around it and code to the new behavior. Its the confusing and unexpected nature of it that leaves me wondering if something else is going on.